# how to get cropped image names and paths after crop by imagemagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

I crop an image file by node module `imagemagick`. It crops successfully, but how to get the names (or paths) of cropped result images

My code:

```
const im = require('imagemagick');
....
const imgFile = "img.png";
im.convert([imgFile, '-crop', '300x300', 'test.png'],
  function(err, stdout){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    // here: I want to get names (or paths) of cropped images
    }
)
```

Comment: try __dirname + "test.png" as last argument